# Как получить данные из потоков не используя вывод для пользователя

Tags: php, guzzle

Всем привет. Используя для REST-клиента библиотеку `GuzzleHttp`.
Написал свой класс (wrapper) для клиента. Теперь появилась необходимость реализовать режим отладки (метод получения данных отладки).

У этой библиотеки есть параметр `'debug' => true`, который можно передать в конструктор.

В документации про этот параметр написано следующее:

> Set to true or set to a PHP stream returned by fopen() to enable debug
>   output with the handler used to send a request. For example, when
>   using cURL to transfer requests, cURL's verbose of CURLOPT_VERBOSE
>   will be emitted. When using the PHP stream wrapper, stream wrapper
>   notifications will be emitted. If set to true, the output is written
>   to PHP's STDOUT. If a PHP stream is provided, output is written to the
>   stream.
>
> **Types**
>
> bool
>
> fopen() resource

Т.е. если передать `true`, то выводится дебаг для всех пользователей через поток STDOUT. 
Либо можно передать хендл на файл, куда будет записываться данные дебага.

Вопрос:

меня вариант с `STDOUT` и выводом в файл не устраивает. Мне нужно значение записать в переменную.

Есть ли какие-тов арианты это сделать, не записывая в файли  потом считывая оттуда?

Возможно, каким-то подобныч образом `file_get_contents("php://stdout")...` ?

Comment: Может как-то добавить в какой-то поток, fopen(STDERR, ..)  потом считать через fscanf(STDERR.. ) но как правильно сделать? чтобы не сломать работу всего проекта, вдруг в этот подок что-то будет добавлен? А мы перезапишем своими данными, или считаем не те данные?

Comment: Слышал, что можно свои врапперы делать, на подобии такого: fopen("myWrapper://") может это можно как-то применить?